# Why does importing have a cost in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, import, multiprocessing

Basically the more imports from different modules I include the longer these multiprocessing tasks take, even if none of the module functions are used. Is each process having to reimport everything or something? What is going on?

```
import time

time1 = time.time()

import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np  # Random imports (not used)
import PIL
import PySide
import pandas
# print time.time() - time1  # here this prints 0.0

class Multi(object):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.q = queue    
    def run(self, a):
        p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(a, q))
        p.start()
        print self.q.get()
        p.join()


class MultiPool(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.pool = mp.Pool(processes = self.N)    
    def run(self):
        result = self.pool.map_async(f1, ((i,) for i in range(self.N)))
        print result.get()


def f(a, q):
    for i in range(10000000):
        b = i
    q.put(b)

def f1(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        b = i
    return b

if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = mp.Queue()
    e = Multi(q)

    # time1 = time.time()
    print f1(0)
    print time.time() - time1

    time1 = time.time()
    e.run('123')
    print time.time() - time1

    time1 = time.time()
    mpool = MultiPool(2)
    mpool.run()
    print time.time() - time1

# Output with random imports:
>9999999
>0.246000051498
>9999999
>0.693000078201
>[9999999, 9999999]
>0.720999956131

# Output without imports:
>9999999
>0.246000051498
>9999999
>0.315999984741
>[9999999, 9999999]
>0.313999891281
```

Comment: Please post the output of your script

Comment: What do you do to remove the imports?  How do you obtain the second output?

Comment: just comment out the imports which are not used. The more imports I add the longer the multiprocessing output takes

Comment: Please check again your code because 1) the value `0.246000051498` cannot be EXACTLY the same in the two case because it should change every start even if you don't change nothing in your code. I just cut and paste your code and every run it change. Moreover it change if I add some import as should be.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the output. Usually it is slightly different

Comment: please uncomment the first `print` and you will see that is NOT 0

Comment: It prints 0.0 on my machine. i5-3570k 16GB

Comment: On my I7 2GHz (little old) I can measure it `0.0727050304413` by just `numpy` and `PIL`. I thing you are going to catch ghosts. For the record python 2.7 and same behavior in python 3.2

Comment: It seems to be taking 0.4s for the imports using multiprocessing which seems way to big..

Comment: That is maybe use a process for small works is not a capital idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `multiprocessing` must import everything in any proces just because are *process* (new applications) and not thread.

What you will measure by your script is the cost of methods execution *plus the cost of process creation*. You can measure the imports cost and they are execute in place exactly where the `import` statements are.

Comment: The first time.time() block does not show a penalty from extra imports. Are imports to __main__ set up before execution of functions?

Comment: @kezzos that is the real puzzle.  Now I  on the tablet. Later I'll try it